# Are all android code on github free to use

Tags: android, apache, github, licensing, android-library

For commercial purposes without mentioning their licence in our apps?

For example android third party libraries?

Can i use android third party libraries in my app without showing their author's name?

> I want to use third party libraries but do not want anybody to know their names!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: no!!!!!!!!!!!!! please.I want to use third party libraries but do not want anybody to know their names!!

Comment: No, always give some credits to the developer who developed that code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about licensing and legal advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most open source repos in github have the **MIT License**, which is a permissive free software license, meaning that it puts only very limited restriction on reuse and has therefore an excellent license compatibility. The MIT license permits reuse within proprietary software provided all copies of the licensed software include a copy of the MIT License terms and the copyright notice.

With an MIT licensed product (not only android code):

**You CAN:**

- re-use the code freely for your own use
- re-use the code freely for    non-commercial AND commercial
  re-distribution, whether in source or    binary form.

**You CANNOT:**

- claim authorship of the software,
- thus you cannot attack the original author for using or publishing
  his original version.

So, yes, you CAN use MIT licensed repos in your commercial application.

Actually nobody cares if you have mentioned their works in your applications. But, **it's a respectful behavior to mention others' works in your project.**

Comment: Even the code which has 'Apache Software License, Version 2.0' is free to use.. many of the Android software/code is licensed with this license.

Comment: Can view edit the source code of a library and under  'Apache Software License, Version 2.0'  use in our own commercial app ?